# unknown type while trying to parse JSON data With SwiftyJSON under iOS 7

Tags: json, swift, ios7, alamofire, swifty-json

I am using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for networking and [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) for parsing server response in my iOS app.

I always get `unknown` while trying to do this `println(JSON(data!))`

Here is my request code :

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString: "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
        .response { (request, response, data, error) in
            println("request ====  \(request)")
            println("response ==== \(response)")
            println("error ==== \(error)")
            println("json ==== \(JSON(data!))")
            println("data ==== \(data)")
    }
```

And here is my console output :

```
request ====  <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x15e9a4e0> { URL: http://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar }
response ==== Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x15ddc910> { URL: http://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar } { status code: 200, headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" = true;
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 430;
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Wed, 04 Feb 2015 09:12:45 GMT";
Server = nginx;
} })
error ==== nil
json ==== unknown
data ==== Optional(<7b0a2020 22617267 73223a20 7b0a2020 20202266 6f6f223a 20226261 72220a20 207d2c20 0a202022 68656164 65727322 3a207b0a 20202020 22416363 65707422 3a20222a 2f2a222c 200a2020 20202241 63636570 742d456e 636f6469 6e67223a 2022677a 69703b71 3d312e30 2c636f6d 70726573 733b713d 302e3522 2c200a20 20202022 41636365 70742d4c 616e6775 61676522 3a202266 723b713d 312e302c 656e3b71 3d302e39 2c64653b 713d302e 382c7a68 2d48616e 733b713d 302e372c 7a682d48 616e743b 713d302e 362c6a61 3b713d30 2e35222c 200a2020 20202248 6f737422 3a202268 74747062 696e2e6f 7267222c 200a2020 20202255 7365722d 4167656e 74223a20 224f7545 73744d6f 6e43616d 696f6e2f 636f6d2e 50697865 6c734163 6164656d 792e4f75 4573744d 6f6e4361 6d696f6e 2028313b 204f5320 56657273 696f6e20 372e312e 32202842 75696c64 20313144 32353729 29220a20 207d2c20 0a202022 6f726967 696e223a 20223139 372e3134 2e31302e 3234222c 200a2020 2275726c 223a2022 68747470 3a2f2f68 74747062 696e2e6f 72672f67 65743f66 6f6f3d62 6172220a 7d0a>)
```

Am  i doing something wrong?

Comment: And if you just do a `println(data)`?

Comment: I get some encoded data on my console

Comment: Could you please post the output?

Comment: You can try `let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)` and `println(json["headers"]["User-Agent"]` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem was relative to the **Alamofire library** under iOS7. I ended up by working with [AFNetworking](https://github.com/afnetworking/afnetworking) and parsing web service response with **SwiftyJSON** without any strange problems.

Answer (score 3):

The `unknown` value being printed is coming from SwiftyJSON. It appears that you are using the incorrect initializer. Instead you want to try the following.

```
var parsingError: NSError?
let json = JSON(data: dataFromServer, error: &error)

println(json)
println(parsingError)
```

This will run `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` over your NSData that you send into SwiftyJSON. If it succeeds, you'll get a valid `JSON` object. If it fails, you will still get your `unknown` type but the `parsingError` will tell you why parsing failed.

One last tip is that you could try to encode the `dataFromServer` to be able to visualize it properly. Here's how you could do that.

```
if let dataFromServer = dataFromServer as? NSData {
    if let encodedData = NSString(data: dataFromServer, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        println(encodedData)
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!